# Computer architecture calculation values

Tags: computer-science, integer-arithmetic

I have homework and i'm confused.... is address or value in the brackets???

Given the following memory and register values.

 Word 700 contains 740

 Word 710 contains 750

 Word 720 contains 710

 Word 730 contains 740

 Word 740 contains 700

 Word 750 contains 700

 Word 760 contains 840

 Word 770 contains 730

 Word 780 contains 770

 Word 790 contains 720

 AX Register contains 710

 BX Register contains 730

 CX Register contains 770

 DX Register contains 760

 Base Register contains 200

What would be the result in following cases?
a) ADD [710], [740]

b) SUB BX, [790]

c) MOV DX, [750]

d) ADD [AX], [730]

e) MUL [DX], 3

Answer (score 0):

The value is in the brackets. The registers in the brackets should be represented by their values too.